# Avoiding long elif - elif code structures when you want to choose a method from a given keyword

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been watching this talk about python styling by Mike Pirnat:

http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2011/pycon-2011--exhibition-of-atrocity.html

However I did not understand one part (starts at 7:00): It is about how to avoid using very long "elif" structures in cases where you want to run a method according to one string instruction. For example we could create a dictionary with each method linked by a keyword:

```
class myOperations():

    def __init__(self):

        self.operation = {'suma':self.sum,
                     'resta':self.minus,
                     'mult':self.multiply,
                    'div':self.divide}


    def sum(self, a,b):
        return a+b

    def minus(self, a,b):
        return a-b

    def multiply(self, a,b):
        return a*b

    def divide(self, a,b):
        return a/b

op = myOperations()

treatment = op.operation['suma']

print treatment(2,3)
```

However, the author says there are ways to completely externalize this process and this way you can avoid defining keywords in the operation dictionary. He gives this structure using the injection decorator I do not understand...

[image]

My question at this point would be: I want to access the different operations on myOperations class using a keyword (and the given methods arguments) which is the more advance way to do it than the procedure on the code above.

Thanks a lot for any advice. Sorry if the question was not clear.

Comment: Isn't "the injection decorator" (whatever that is) advanced enough for you? It looks like it can read minds and DWIM (do what I mean).

Comment: It is of course. I just do not know how to use. I have been searching for examples but I do not know how to move them to this simple example of mine... I am checking the a solution with the .getattr method is better or not